# Настройка Apache. Группы, роли

Tags: linux, apache, безопасность

Всем доброго времени суток!

Подскажите, пожалуйста, литературу, где написано какие должны быть группы на сервере(Linux), какие у них должны быть права. Из-под каких учетных записей запускать: nginx, php, mysql  и т.д.

В сети про саму настройку/установку написано, а вот с точки зрения безопасности(из-под каких учеток запускать) не написано(не находил).

Спасибо!

Comment: Из под своих собственных. mysql от пользователя mysql, nginx от www, php - от имени владельца сайта.

Comment: @МАН69К что значит nginx от www? от имени владельца сайта - это вообще кто?

Comment: Значит запустить веб-сервер nginx от пользователя www. В его документации именно такое имя в примерах и указано. Хотя, разумеется, можете поставить и другое имя. Владелец сайта - пользователь, которому принадлежат файлы сайта. Они же у вас не root'у ведь принадлежат, правда?